# Is it possible to join a new community from the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

I am new to Stack Exchange and have been trying to find how to join other Stack Exchange communities through the Android app without success. Does the feature exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you go to some community you're not a member in. You try to vote, comment, etc., i.e. do something.

The app asks: "Wanna join?".
You click: "yup, why not?"

(I am not sure about the exact wording though.)